# Excel VBA Chart Generation

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, graph, scatter

I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm trying to implement a certain type of graph based off of the following example data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjZu7FPYRXsjdEJMLTN2MTZhUldpNnhYeW0wNF8taFE&output=html

I've attempted using the macro recorder but I haven't had any luck getting it to work as required.

I'd like to have a ScatterPlot with lines and Markers with the X-Values of the chart equal to the dates presented, the left Y axis be a range from 0 to 4 (with the steps inbetween equal to 1) and I'd also like to have a second y-axis where the max is the max number presented in the data (so in this case 45). Also, is there any way to name the series other than 'Series1', 'Series2' etc.?

In the end I'll cut down the number of series (probably a max of six).

Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is the code provided by the macro recorder:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("TimelineGenerator!$C$1:$W$11")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 4
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
```

But when I execute this to generate my graph via vba, it has the dates as series instead of the xValues of the chart.

Comment: What Excel version are you using? The macro recorder with charts was good on Excel 2003, pathetic on 2007, decent on 2010 (I haven't tried the 2013 yet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried exactly that and I still have the series as the dates and the have the values as the X-axis. It works if I select the data manually and create the chart, but not via vba.

Comment: To get a better idea of what I'm talking about, the chart on the left is inserted via excel and the chart on the right uses the vba code listed above:

http://i.imgur.com/WefQMKE.png

Comment: Does Column C actually contain your dates?  Your sample sheet1 looks like it would be in Column A

Comment: @pnuts Yes, but he also states that the image is form him manually selecting the range. And the macro is wrong. The macro was also recorded, and could have just took in the wrong range.

Comment: Did you try using the PlotBy argument for the SetSourceData command? It will control whether it's by row or column, and may help you get the dates where you expect them.

Comment: Before you set the source data, clear the cell at the top left of the data range. This blank cell tells Excel that the first row and first column are not regular data, so Excel will use one for X values and the other for series names. If the first row does not contain labels, insert a row for these labels, keeping the first cell blank.